# How do I build a Universal macOS Binary for python 2.7.18 using pyenv?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, pyenv, usd

I'm trying to build a Universal Binary (so both x86_64 and arm64) binary for python 2.7.18 using pyenv with this command

`CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib" arch -x86_64 pyenv install 2.7.18`

and this is the output I get

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-2.7.18.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tar.xz
Installing Python-2.7.18...
patching file configure
patching file configure.ac
patching file setup.py
patching file Mac/Tools/pythonw.c
patching file setup.py
patching file Doc/library/ctypes.rst
patching file Lib/test/test_str.py
patching file Lib/test/test_unicode.py
patching file Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c
patching file Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c
patching file Modules/_ctypes/ctypes.h
patching file Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c
patching file setup.py
patching file Mac/Modules/qt/setup.py
patching file setup.py
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
ERROR: The Python zlib extension was not compiled. Missing the zlib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.3 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/fj/mn4vy20j4gl9d_71mf3n3hf00000gn/T/python-build.20220207214945.25127
Results logged to /var/folders/fj/mn4vy20j4gl9d_71mf3n3hf00000gn/T/python-build.20220207214945.25127.log

Last 10 log lines:
rm -f /Users/[...]/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/share/man/man1/python.1
(cd /Users/[...]/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/share/man/man1; ln -s python2.1 python.1)
if test "xno" != "xno"  ; then \
        case no in \
            upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
            install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
        esac; \
         ./python.exe -E -m ensurepip \
            $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
    fi
```

Is there any other way to get python 2.7 as Universal or x86_64 binary? Preferably something that doesn't break homebrew or macOS.

I know that python 2 is deprecated, but Apple USDConvert tools only run under python 2 and Autodesk FBX and pxr plugin only run under x86_64. Python2 was removed from system in macOS 12.3 beta which complicates things even further.

Comment: If it's any help, MacPorts' [python27](https://ports.macports.org/port/python27/) has a [`universal` variant](https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/blob/2157941de15b6c29388331631640c04719220deb/lang/python27/Portfile#L220-L232). Here's [patch-configure-universal.diff](https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/blob/2157941de15b6c29388331631640c04719220deb/lang/python27/files/patch-configure-universal.diff), and [configure.universal_cflags](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/reference.phases.html#reference.phases.configure.universal) seems to be `-arch arm64 -arch x86_64`